# Language localization in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, localization

I need comments on my solution of a website localization system.

Table **Content**:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
Page    varchar(30) YES     NULL     
Locale  varchar(10) YES     NULL     
Data    longtext    YES     NULL
```

My thought is to store each page and each locale into the Content table. For example:

```
index.php en_GB {data}
index.php de_DE {data}
```

The Data field would consist of a json_encoded array in which the text of each of the page elements would be stored. For example:

```
$data['Headline1'] = 'The Headline';
$data['Welcome'] = 'The welcome text.';
```

I have yet to implement it, but I plan on using **memcached** to improve performance - and from the little I know this is the perfect kind of data to use it on since it is not prone to be updated very often.

Is this good or bad, should it all be scrapped? Comments please!

Comment: recently i've used gettext with poedit to achieve that (the same solution used by wordpress), it is not that difficult to build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

1. Don't store translations per page, this would cause alot of redundant data as some translations will occur om multiple pages.
2. I advice against throwing all translations into one field in the database, add an entry for each translated sentence.
3. Replace locale (varchar) with an unsigned tinyint and create an index on it, please the locales in an locale table.

Something along the likes of:

```
translationId | localeId | translationKey | translationText
```

Comment: The site will be under very heavy load. I want to make the number of queries kept to a minimum, that's why I opted to get a whole page for a certain locale in one go. What's your thoughts on that? The locale => int idea is great, I'll use that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do localization in PHP use [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) and you will have time do implement other features too, instead of building your own localization system.

Do not worry about speed, php gettext extension runs faster than using strings arrays.

Comment: I wouldn't use anything that relies on set locale.

Comment: I am reluctant on using additional plugins since I want full control of the data. I will let my users translate the site into their respective language and that implementation will obviously be coded by me. I will have to read up on gettext (and I also saw something about a Zend plugin). If it is as fast as you say, it sure sounds promising.