# PHP - phrases/word translations in a file, best way to do it.. array, variables?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I am developing a multi-langual website. Language variables (phrases/word translations) will be entered in a specific file (one different file for each language)

I wanted to know the best way to enter the phrases/word translations, should I use a normal array?

e.g

Filename = English.php

```
   <?php
   $translations = array();
   $translations['phrase1'] = "this";
   $translations['phrase2'] = "that";
   ..
   ?>
```

and in the template file

```
   <?php
   include("English.php");
   echo $translations['phrase1'];
```

etc...

I am pretty new to PHP so I am just looking for the best way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry... The code I have entered isn't shown, I must have forgotten html tags or something.

Comment: Indent your code by four spaces, or select it and hit the `{}` button in the toolbar! http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Language localization in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303857/language-localization-in-php) and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+localization)

Comment: You're right. I'll look further.. Thanks

Comment: check out [strtr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple of ways to do this, the two things that pop-off my head right now are:

1) Have a look at [gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gettext.php) & [GNU gettext page](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Introduction). An example implementation of this to look at is [Aur Website of ArchLinux](http://aur.archlinux.org/). They their app support multiple languages & its all dynamic. user can can switch between languages easily. The source code is available [here](http://projects.archlinux.org/aur.git/tree/), study it & see how they did it.

2) Other option could be use a framework like [cakephp](http://cakephp.org), as most of these frameworks [have translations support](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1229/Internationalizing-Your-Application)

Hope it somewhat helps